# DE question i have no idea how to solve

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

So i found this question and have tried substituting into variable separation or as in homogenous equations but cant seem to solve it

The question: the solution of

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$

is given as:

Comment: Do not use the ² symbol for powers. Use ^2 instead.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$
Substitute $u=y-2,v=x+2$
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{(u+v)^2}{uv}$$
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{u}{v}+\frac{v}{u}+2$$
Substitute $u=tv \implies u'=t'v+t$
$$v \dfrac {dt}{dv}=\frac{1+2t}{t}$$
It's separable.

Comment: Thanks! That helped

Comment: You are welcomed @Kaustav

Answer (score 1):

You set $y-2=u(x)(x+2)$ and insert to get a separable equation
$$
(x+2)u'+u=\frac{(1+u)^2}{u}.
$$